# Method setExceptionListener not permitted after spring-jms update

Tags: spring, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am using `@JmsListener` to consume messages from IBM MQ configured on WAS.
I can see the following log on the application startup:

```
DEBUG o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer Could not establish shared JMS Connection - leaving it up to asynchronous invokers to establish a Connection as soon as possible javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Method setExceptionListener not permitted
at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSCMUtils.methodNotPermittedException(JMSCMUtils.java:268)
at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle.checkRestrictedMethod(JMSConnectionHandle.java:867)
at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle.setExceptionListener(JMSConnectionHandle.java:361)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.prepareConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:355)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.getConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:328)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:243)
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:197)
[...]
```

But then it seems to connecting just fine and messages are being consumed as expected:

```
DEBUG o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer JMS message listener invoker needs to establish shared Connection
DEBUG o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

After updating `spring-jms` dependency from 5.2.22.RELEASE version to 5.3.27, the connection is not getting refreshed and I started to receive the below exception:

```
ERROR o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'XXX' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Method setExceptionListener not permitted
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Method setExceptionListener not permitted
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSCMUtils.methodNotPermittedException(JMSCMUtils.java:268)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle.checkRestrictedMethod(JMSConnectionHandle.java:867)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionHandle.setExceptionListener(JMSConnectionHandle.java:361)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.prepareConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:446)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:355)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.getConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:328)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:243)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:197)
    [...]
```

I'm not sure if there's any update I missed to do. Would you be able to provide me with some hints?

```
@Transactional
@JmsListener(containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory", destination = "XXX")
public void handleMessage(String message){ //... }
```

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJms
public class MqConfig{

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory() throws NamingException{
   return (ConnectionFactory) new JndiObjectFactoryBean().getJndiTemplate().lookup("jms/MqConnFact"); 
}

@Bean
public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory() throws NamingException{
   CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
   cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqConnectionFactory());
   cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheConsumers(true);
   cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheProducers(true);
   cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(10);
   cachingConnectionFactory.setReconnectOnException(true);
   return cachingConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() throws NamingException{
   DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory containerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
   containerFactory.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory());
   containerFactory.setConcurrency("1");
   containerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(2);
   containerFactory.setTransactionManager(jmsTransactionManager());
   containerFactory.setCacheLevelName("CACHE_CONSUMER");
   containerFactory.setSessionTransacted(true);
   containerFactory.setReceiveTimeout(60000);
   return containerFactory;
}
```

EDIT:
I noticed that the code stops working when changing spring dependencies version from 5.3.25 to 5.3.26. I took a look at [changes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/releases/tag/v5.3.26) made for version 5.3.26 - and suspect that the change in behavior could be related to [this item](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30051), however I'm still not sure how to resolve it

Comment: Don't upgrade individual dependencies of Spring jars, upgrade all of them. Never mix jars/modules from different ersions of a framework that is trouble waiting to happen.

Comment: Yes, I have updated all spring dependencies to same version. Even if the rest of spring dependencies stays 5.3.27 and I only revert spring-jms to 5.2.22.RELEASE, it works fine.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace (I suppose there is more) and your dependencies (your maven or gradle file should suffice).

Comment: Ok, actually I noticed it works fine till 5.3.25, starts to fail from 5.3.26

Comment: Did you try 5.3.29 which is the latest version for that range, if it still persists you might want to create an issue with Spring.

Comment: Yes, I tried and it failed too. Please find my edit with additional logs and reference to spring doc changelog

Comment: As stated -> *if it still persists you might want to create an issue with Spring*. It might have even happend before the update (as apparently IBM MQ disallowes it) but was silently swallowed and as the `Connection` was still being set it had a (yet broken/inconsistent) `Connection`. This state is now being prevented from happening (which is correct imho). But you might want to raise an issue in the spring issue tracker nonetheless.